# Is there a way to prevent gnuplot from using solid points?

Tags: gnuplot

I am automatically generating .plt files for an unknown number of input files per graph. My problem is when gnuplot chooses solid shapes for the points (filled in square), the solid points overwhelm all the other types of points. In this image of [gnuplot point types](http://stelweb.asu.cas.cz/~nemeth/work/stuff/gnuplot/gnuplot-line-and-point-types.png)
is there a way for me to say do not use 5,7,11,13,etc? Or perhaps the inverse of this (use 1,2,3,4,6,8,etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set linetype` to select the point types which are used:

```
set linetype 1 pt 1
set linetype 2 pt 2
set linetype 3 pt 3
set linetype 4 pt 4
set linetype 5 pt 6
set linetype 6 pt 8
set linetype 7 pt 10
set linetype 8 pt 12

set samples 11
plot for [i=1:8] i*x with points notitle
```

[image]

Comment: I see! I didn't know you could override the linetypes like that. Thanks!